# SharePoint 2013 Newsfeed Following Publishing Pages

Tags: publishing-page, mysite, newsfeed, following

I got a issue with not being able to track changes to a Page on the MySite Newsfeed if im following it.

If I follow a document (`.docx` etc) I get notified when the document has been changed. But not for the `.aspx` file.

See the below picture:

Here I have followed a `.docx` document and I get notified of the changes that Administrator has done. But Administrator has also changed `test200.aspx` and no changes are returned on the NewsFeed. 
[image]

Anyone got a workaround or code piece to solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the "Content Following Item Updated Event Receiver" event receiver to the pages library.

Farm Solution with Feature and Module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="850">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>Content Following Item Updated Event Receiver 850</Name>
      <Type>ItemUpdated</Type>
      <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
      <Class>Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentFollowingItemEventReceiver</Class>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Or PowerShell:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –erroraction SilentlyContinue

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity URL

$pagesListId = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPagesListId($web)
$pagesList = $web.Lists[$pagesListId]

$eventReceiver = $pagesList.EventReceivers.Add()
$eventReceiver.Name = "Content Following Item Updated Event Receiver 850"
$eventReceiver.Type = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverType]::ItemUpdated
$eventReceiver.Assembly = "Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
$eventReceiver.Class = "Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentFollowingItemEventReceiver"
$eventReceiver.Update()

$web.Dispose()
```